# Spring boot 2.6.4 all my variables of type date and localtime gives only number without format

Tags: json, spring-boot, date, format, localtime

My spring boot project has a problem, I updated from version `2.5.1` to `2.6.4` and now all my variables of type `date` and `localtime` are given number without format
examples **:**

```
date = "2022-03-04" in JSON are "1646352000000"
```

and my localtime are like this **:**

```
localtime = "09:00:00" in JSON is "9"
```

any suggestions on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure Jackson in order to avoid serialization of Java dates in timestamp.

You should add

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
<version>2.9.5</version>
```

and configure it like this :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```